# How to remove a div with particular class or id from a string using jquery?

Tags: jquery

i have a string

```
var c = '<div class="main">
             <div class="child1">text 1</div>
             <div class="child1">text 2</div>
             <div class="child2">text 2</div>
         </div>';
```

Now i want to remove `child2` from this string only ..

I tried this

```
var $c = $(c).not('child2');
```

but its not working 
Any body have solution regarding this. Please let me know

Thanks

Comment: Did you get the solution for your question?

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
var c ='<div class="main"><div class="child1"> text 1</div><div class="child1"> text 2</div><div class="child2"> text 2</div></div>';
var $c = $(c); //Get the JQ object to a var
$c.find('.child2').remove(); //Remove it from there
c = $c.html(); //Get back the html
```

Unfortunately

`$(c).find('.child2').remove()` wont remove it at source as it is not in DOM and is just a string. So you need to get the object to a temp variable and then remove it from that and get back the html string out of it.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3PUMm/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `$.parseHTML` first then remove

```
var c ='<div class="main"><div class="child1"> text 1</div><div class="child1"> text 2</div><div class="child2"> text 2</div></div>';
c=$.parseHTML(c);
$(c).find('.child2').remove();
console.log($(c));
```

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/78m4J/

Answer (score 0):

Without jquery:

```
var tempDiv = document.createElement('div');
var c ='<div class="main"><div class="child1"> text 1</div><div class="child1"> text 2</div><div class="child2"> text 2</div></div>';
var removableChild = tempDiv.getElementsByClassName("child2")[0];
removableChild.parentElement.removeChild(removableChild);
var c = tempDiv.innerHTML;
```